# jQuery - Addition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an issue in doing a simple addition and save the value in a variable.

Basically I have the following code:

```
    var accsen;
    var lowsev = parseInt(accsen);
    var hisev = parseInt(accsen) + parseInt(0.65);

    console.log('Lowsev: ' + lowsev);
    console.log('Hisev: '  + hisev + ' Type: ' + typeof(hisev));
    console.log('Accsen: ' + accsen);
```

The variable accsen is being given a value from the database.  Lowsev is being assigned the same value as accsen,while hisev is being assigned the value of accsen + 0.65.

However the issue I am having is that both lowsev and hisev are remaining 0.  On doing console.log I get these values:

Lowsev: 0
Hisev: 0   Type: undefined
Accsen: 0.75

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in the addition?  Am I using the correct operators?

Comment: "*...The variable accsen is being given a value from the database...*," I may be going blind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lowsev is being assigned the same value as accsen" It's not, you're rounding it to an integer.

But `parseInt()` doesn't round properly. 0.75 comes out as 0, so it's working. Assuming you actually want to round these values try

```
var accsen;
var lowsev = Math.round(accsen);
var hisev = Math.round(accsen) + Math.round(0.65);
```

**EDIT** given the response

Your JS is treating accsen as a string, you need to convert to a number

```
var accsen = '0.75'; // as other people have noted this val in your code is missing.
var lowsev = parseFloat(accsen);
var hisev = parseFloat(accsen) + 0.65;
```

Comment: as such I do not want to round the value.  I need the decimal places.  All I need to do is setting the value of accsen to lowsev and do a simple addition in case of hisev of (0.75 + 0.65)

Comment: how can I keep the same value (rather than rounding)? and make the neccessary addition?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.